# Bootstrap 3.3.4 navbar issue - positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

**Here is the MarkUp:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Kellumonline</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
                    <li><a href="tech/index.html">Tech</li>
                    <li><a href="gaming/index.html">Gaming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="skate/index.html">Skate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**[Website](http://www.kellumonline.com/)** where the code is currently published on

I have no CSS styling any of the containers or elements.  I seriously have like 3 styles:

- one is pulling a font from Google,
- the second is specifying a width and height for my jumbotron,
- the third is specifying the margin for my 3 columns at the bottom of
  my home page.

I am working on my website and need some help figuring out why my navbar links are spaced the way they are.

Also, my contact page is not displaying correctly and it has the same code in it as the other pages.

Any help, feedback or constructive criticism is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific what are you are asking for?

Comment: I have since fixed most of my issues.  I still can't figure out why my <li> elements have to be directly beside each other so that my navbar looks right(side by side horizontally)  When I stack them in the code, it places them all over the place in the navbar itself.  Only when I put no spaces, line drops or line breaks will it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's very stupid...*

The navbar in your contact page has this following class:

```
class="navbar navbar-incerse navbar-static"
```

**So**

Change **incerse** by **inverse**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it, I can see the the Home link and the Tech link don't have their closing `</a>` tags.  Add those in and that should sort it out.

Also, @yenne-info has the correct answer to your Contact page issue.

Comment: Thank you @ric0c.  I have since fixed my issues due to both of your help.  I still can't figure out why my <li> elements have to be directly beside each other so that my navbar looks right(side by side horizontally)  When I stack them in the code, it places them all over the place in the navbar itself.  Only when I put no spaces, line drops or line breaks will it work... Not sure if you can help but it would be amazing.

Comment: @RyanKellum no probs.  Can't really say for sure without an example but you might want to check your text-editor, my initial thought is that it might be trying to be add additional code when you press space or enter in an attempt to be helpful.  Are you coding manually or using a visual/WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Manually. I'm using sublime text 3 Trial version.

Comment: @RyanKellum Hmmm... then I'm not sure what it is.  If you continue having a whitespace problem it would be best to conclude this question and open up this new issue in a separate post with examples.